# Why "pre" function is mostly used with userSchema while using bcryptjs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I have mostly seen "pre" function to be used as userSchema.pre('save', async function(){..}) while using bcrypt in express.
 I know it is a middleware, runs before .save() function to encrypt password but what is the logic of using "pre" with userSchema?.. like userSchema.pre()

Comment: This is not an express middleware - like you would add with app.use() - that is executed on each request. This is a mongoose model middleware that is executed only for a specific operation - save - on a specific model - User..

Answer (score 0):

when we use bcrypt, we need to hash the password before (pre) add it to the database, so this process done pre-save, not after(post) save, we cannot hash password after save it, it hashed before save

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's just a convient way of manipulating documents before they are stored, e.g. in order to ensure that passwords are not stored in plaintext and converted to a hash instead (which is often done using bcrypt as you mentioned).

Here's a nice article that explains in detail: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2019/02/hash-password-data-mongodb-mongoose-bcrypt/

Comment: @ritik jain: any feedback?